# Samsung 2013 tv emulator crashes, how can I use 2012 instead?

Tags: emulation, samsung-smart-tv, television

I have Samsung SDK 4.1 installed. It gives me three Samsung TV emulators:
2011, 2012 and 2013.

Emulators 2011 and 2012 work fine.
Emulator 2013 crashes.

I do not want to waste more time trying to make 2013 work. Instead I would like to use 2012.

How can I configure Eclipse Samsung Smart TV IDE to use 2012 emulator instead of 2013?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already wasted my time to stop crash in 2013 emulator. You must have the 32 bit version of the trio OS , JDK and Samsung SDK.
So i created virtual machine via VMWare player and installed 32 bit windows 7, then I installed respectively ( jdk , directx 11 , Samsung SDK ). It works finally.

I don't know how to configure eclips to run 2012 instead, but i think you have two options till you find a configuration somewhere to point to 2012 emulator.
**Option 1 :** Put your app in < sdk root folder >/app then go to start menu , open 2012 emulator , click open app button , select your app.
**Option 2:** Try uninstall SDK then install it again excluding 2013 emulator in the setup wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Try to

1. Open "Samsung Smart TV SDK" menu
2. Choose "Samsung Smart TV SDK Preferences"
3. Change Emulator Version to 2012 or Emulator 3.5